# on MAC Monterey, git clone working but git push fails because it uses wrong ssh key on push?

Tags: git, macos

My ~/.ssh/config has this entry

```
Host personal
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519personalgithub
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I git clone with

```
git clone git@personal:deanhiller/testwithexecutor-all.git
```

That works fine.  My .git/config file has it correct like so

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@personal:deanhiller/testwithexecutor-all.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

When I git push however, I get this error

```
dean@Deans-MacBook-Pro testwithexecutor-all % git push
ERROR: Permission to deanhiller/testwithexecutor-all.git denied to deancompanyuser
```

It is using the wrong username and not the username deanhiller!!!  Why is this?

If I do a git config -l, I have no user name set (desired so I can easily just work out of repositories without screwing around cloning and pushing very easily).   I do not want to keep changing usernames or having to set the username every time I clone a repo.  Where is it even grabbing deancompanyuser from???

Comment: `ssh -Tv git@personal` ?

Comment: very weird response from that command @phd .  The response was-> Hi deancompanyuser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: Double check you've uploaded `id_ed25519personalgithub.pub` to `deanhiller` account and the other public key to `deancompanyuser` account. Please show the entire `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Did you configure SSH at GitHub?

Comment: @phd The ssh command says successful as I noted in my comment so they keys are correct or that would not have connected (the ssh piece), right?   But yes, the key is uploaded and all was working fine before I added another user to use for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

First, add User git in your config file:

```
Host personal
   HostName github.com
   User git                                     <=====
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519personalgithub
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

That way, you can clone with `personal:...` instead of `git@personal`.
And you can test which user is authenticated with that key using `ssh -Tv personal` (instead of `ssh -Tv git@personal`)

Second, `id_ed25519personalgithub.pub` has been registered to the `deancompanyuser`'s account, not `deanhiller`'s.
As a result, `deancompanyuser` does not have the right to push to a repository they do not own.

But it can clone deanhiller's repository, if said repository is a public one.

Answer (score 0):

The user `deancompanyuser` is very likely saved on your **Keychain Access**. So open the Keychain Access on your Mac and search about "GitHub" and remove the entry. After that, it should no longer show the *wrong* user.

Comment: I ran into another post and search login->passwords and a whole slew of other locations and cannot find that at all for some reason.

Comment: I saw the ssh key tied to that user in there and deleted that but that didn't fix it still :(

Comment: I had a similar problem after I  added a new github account with ssh authentication. My keychain  insisted on using the the new ssh key for both accounts, and I could not get into the original account until I deleted the new ssh key from my keychain.